# Login sencillo con SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos con SpringBoot... Quiero hacer un servicio de Login en el cual le pones un usuario y una contraseña y si es correcto te devuelve los datos del usuario.

De momento con hacer que te devuelva los datos del usuario me conformo, pero si puedo resolver lo que quiero, lo agradecería.

El problema que tengo son 2.
No sé como enviar 2 parámetros "nombreUsuario","contraseña" por eso de momento sólo envío 1.

Controlador:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value={"/usu"})
public class UsuController {

    @Autowired
    UsuService usuRepository;


     @RequestMapping("/")
        String home() {
            return "Servicio Usuario!";
     }


          @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, path = "/Login/{userName}" ,  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Usuario Login(@PathVariable("userName") String userName) {
        Usuario tasks = usuRepository.getUsu(userName);
        return tasks; 
    }
```

Interface:

```
public interface UsuService { 
      public List<Usuario> getUsus() ;
      public Usuario getUsu(String name);
}
```

Service:

```
@Override
    public Usuario getUsu(String user) {
    Usuario usu;
    return usu = usuRepository.findOne(user);

    }
```

Repositorio

```
package prueba.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import prueba.Usuario;

public interface UsuRepository extends CrudRepository<Usuario,String>{

}
```

Usuario Clase

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuario")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Usuario {

     @Id
     @Column(name="id")
     private int id;

     @Column(name="name")
     private String name;

     @Column(name="email")
     private String email;

     public Usuario() {
    }
     public Usuario(int id, String name, String email) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "usuario [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }


}
```

Ejecutar

```
http://localhost:8080/usu/Login/edu
```

Error

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Jul 02 10:31:34 CEST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Provided id of the wrong type for class prueba.Usuario. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class prueba.Usuario. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
```

Ya hice una prueba devolviendo **todos** los usuarios y **funciona**.

De momento quiero que al poner Mi nombre de Usuario, me devuelva mis datos, y después haré lo del Login con contraseña.Gracias.

Comment: Creo que has dejado fuera de la pregunta lo más importante: la clase del atributo `usuRepository`

Comment: @Pablo Lozano ya está la clase y el repositorio.

Answer (score 2):

Al tratarse de un login deberias usar un POST, y en vez de recuperar un @PathVariable, puedes recuperar un @RequestBody de tipo complejo, donde incluyas tanto el Username como la Password.

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public Usuario Login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
     request.getUsername();
     request.getPassword();
}



public class LoginRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

En tu repositorio tienes

```
public interface UsuRepository extends CrudRepository<Usuario,String> { }
```

Es decir, le dices a Spring que ese repositorio va a manejar la entidad `Usuario` y que su identificador será un `String`.

Pero luego en Usuario tienes:

```
public class Usuario {

     @Id
     @Column(name="id")
     private int id;
     //...
}
```

Es decir, el id es un `int` (o `Integer`, al usar clases), lo que te obligaría a definir el repositorio como

```
public interface UsuRepository extends CrudRepository<Usuario,Integer> {
    Usuario findByEmail(String email);
```

}

Los repositorios de Spring [tienen una convención con los nombres de los métodos](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation):

```
ClaseEntidad findBy<nombreDelCampo>[And|Or<nombreDelSegundoCampo> (campo[,segundoCampo]);
```

### PS:

Por otro lado, el método `findOne` no existe en CrudRepository [desde hace un año](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/commit/727ab8384cac21e574526f325e19d6af92b8c8df?diff=unified), se cambió a findById, si estás empezando un proyecto te recomiendo actualizar las librerías.

### PPS:

Lo que necesitas realmente es usar Spring Security, pero los cambios son demasiado grandes para una respuesta aquí, te recomendaría que intentases seguir un tutorial sobre el tema.

Comment: Perdona, tengo que hacerlo con la versión  <version>1.5.14.RELEASE</version> del SpringBoot,¿ qué método es entonces ? porque el findById no existe en 1.5.14.

Comment: Si tienes que hacerlo con esa versión, adelante... simplemente te avisaba de que es una versión ya anticuada

Comment: pero me sigue dando el error...  return usuRepository.findOne(user); user es una String

Comment: He editado, a ver si ahora me explico mejor

Comment: al cambiar a una versión del pom.xml que no fuese 1.5.10.RELEASE cuando importaba el websecurity, daba errores en eclipse que no tenían ni pies ni cabeza, así que cogí la 1,5,10. Ahora mismo tengo que escribir otro problema que tengo con Spring, tardaré 5minutos, gracias.